# Python "time" package installation error on PyCharm

Tags: python, time, pycharm, package

I am using PyCharm (v 2020.2.3) and I am trying to install the package "time" (in order to use the sleep function) but it throws an error. Earlier it was related to the pip version, so I upgraded the pip from 20.2 to 20.3. But now it throws a different error.

I am a little new to Python and tried to make sense of the GitHub link provided in the error but not very sure.

Thanks in advance!

*DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for time*

Comment: Are you trying to install via the PyCharm Interpreter Settings or via pip on command line?

Comment: Actually are you sure you need to install it?  Usually the time package comes automatically included with all major python distributions.

Comment: @tclarke13 is right. you don't need to install the time package it's included in python

Answer (score 2):

The `time` module is built-in to Python.

Just import it directly. No need to install any packages.